# Guice per request module override?

Tags: java, scope, guice

Something I have seen over and over again in the code base I work in is a scenario where multiple factories or other object deciders will take in the same parameter and decide on an implementation based on that parameter.

```
interface Foo {
    foo();
}

interface Bar {
    bar();
}

class FooProvider {

    ... members constructor etc... 

    Foo get(BazType bazType) {
        switch (bazType) {
           case BAZ_A:
              return bazA;
           case BAZ_B:
              return bazB;
              ....
        }
    }
}

class BarProvider {
    Bar get(BazType bazType) {
        ...same as fooFactory
    }
}

... more interfaces and providers follow
```

These providers(factories?  Not sure what to call them) will be called one or more times in the lifetime of a request in possibly different classes, but the BazType will be defined and final at the beginning of the request.  I find it redundant and potentially dangerous that we have to do this many times when it should only need to be done once.

Is it possible to instead define the implementations and bind them all in a specific module and load the needed module on a per request/thread basis?  I see that there is a Modules.override() but that seems to be more of a one time thing to swap out production code for test or development code and not what I need.  Obviously I'm not going to want to create an injector for every request I serve.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out guice's multi binding extension. It lets you predefine maps containing your providers and then inject that map and select from it.

- [Multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings)
- [MapBinder](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't really get me what I want though.  I would be replacing every switch statement with a map.get(BazType).  I agree that would be somewhat of an improvement over what we currently do(it has been debated here), but it's still a decision being made many times throughout the request flow instead of once.